How to Configure VS Code Testing Tab for Cucumber.js with TypeScript and Playwright to run and debug tests?
Description:
I'm working on a project using TypeScript and Playwright, and I'm writing tests with Cucumber.js. I can successfully run the tests from the terminal using the script defined in my package.json:
"scripts": { 
  "test:cucumber": "npx cucumber-js --config src/config/cucumber.js src/features"
}

When I run npm run test:cucumber, everything works fine.
However, I want to run and debug my tests from the Testing tab in Visual Studio Code. I've searched for extensions and tried ones like CucumberJS Test Runner and Cucumber JS Test Runner, but I've had issues configuring them properly.
I couldn't find official documentation on how to set up the Testing tab to read from my cucumber.js configuration file.
Does anyone know how to configure the Testing tab in VS Code to work with my existing Cucumber.js setup? How can I set it up to run and debug tests directly from VS Code Test tab?
Additional Information:
Technologies Used: TypeScript, Playwright, Cucumber.js, I already have Test Explorer UI extension as well as Cucumber extension.
Project Structure:
project-root/
├── src/
│   ├── features/
│   │   └── *.feature
│   ├── steps/
│   │   └── *.ts
│   └── config/
│       └── cucumber.js
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json

Package.json installed:
 "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^11.1.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.49.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.9.1",   
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  }

What I've Tried: Installed extensions like CucumberJS Test Runner and Cucumber JS Test Runner but faced configuration issues.
Searched official documentation and forums but couldn't find a solution tailored to my setup (TypeScript + Playwright + Cucumber.js).
my current settings.json includes so far only cucumber.features and cucumber.glue sections:
"cucumber.glue": [
        "src/steps/*.ts"
    ],
    "cucumber_runner.features": [
        "src/features/**/*.feature",
    ],

Question: Is there a way to configure Visual Studio Code so that the Testing tab recognizes and runs my Cucumber.js tests using my existing cucumber.js configuration? If so, how can I achieve this?
Any guidance, configuration examples, or extension recommendations that could help me resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

looked at the README of Cucumber JS Test Runner and it clear what settings to change

if you use extensions also provide links to the Market Place pages or github repos

Regarding cucumber-test-runner, there's an issue with versions higher than 9.5.X - https://github.com/Balrog994/cucumber-test-runner/issues/19 :
Works with "@cucumber/cucumber": "^9.5.1"
Fails with "@cucumber/cucumber": "^10.5.1"
My question: How to configure the VS Code Testing tab for Cucumber.js with TypeScript and Playwright to run and debug tests? Ideally for "@cucumber/cucumber": "^11.1.0", not focusing on these extensions specifically but open to other solutions/packages for the latest versions taking into accounts that both of them may not support latest cucumber version.

Have you tried Aristotelos CucumberJS Test Extension. It is a fork of Balrog994 and he is actively adding stuff, maybe create an issue at that repo if it does not work for cucumber v11

Installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aristotelos.cucumber-test-extension solved the problem. FYI - you just need to add proper cucumber.yml with paths to steps, hooks, features and add requireModule e.g. :
default:
requireModule:
- ts-node/register
require:
- pathToSteps
- pathToHooks
publishQuiet: true
features:
- pathTofeatures
Thanks rioV8 for support.
